# In R convert character encoding to UTF-8 (not using stringi)

Tags: r, stringr

I want to convert character strings to `UTF-8`. At the moment, I've managed to do this using `stringi`, like this:

```
test_string <- c("Fiancé is great.")
stringi::stri_encode(test_string, "UTF-8")
```

However, how can I do the same using R `base` or `stringr`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iconv function may a choice.
Example if current encoding is latin1

> iconv(test_string, "latin1", "UTF-8")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Encoding` and `enc2utf8` from `base`:

```
test_string <- c("Fiancé is great.")
Encoding(test_string)
# [1] "latin1"

Encoding(test_string) <- Encoding(enc2utf8(test_string))
Encoding(test_string)
# [1] "UTF-8"
```

And you can find more alternatives [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/279354_f552c4c41852439f910ad620763960b6.html).